# ADO.Net Entity Framework and dynamic order by

Tags: entity-framework

I currently have the below code to fetch data from my Entity framework model.

```
return db.Tasks.Where(t => (t.TaskStatuses.TaskStatusId.Equals(currentStatus) | currentStatus == -1) &
                                        (t.Projects.ProjectId.Equals(projectId) | projectId == -1) &
                                        (assignedToGuid == rnd | t.AssignedTo.UserId.Equals(assignedToGuid)));
```

I now want this to order the data, the function takes 2 stings OrderField and OrderDirection, is there anyway I can change my query to dynamically order by these variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GavD,

The Dynamic Linq library will allow you to dynamically order your queries.  See the following article for more information:

Dynamic Linq: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work anymore since EF Feature CTP5 (an exception is thrown). Hopefully EF will be fixed before RTM.